# When I run my Website, the master page background is missing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have a master page with a background and 3-column layout. The start page "default.aspx" is a content Web Form and is linked to the master page. At the design time, everything looks great but when run, the master page background is invisible. It disappears.

How to fix this?

### ** Edited **

**Master Page Form Code**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Live</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Stylesheets/MasterStyleSheet.css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="masterform" runat="server">
    <div id="divBanner" class="BannerDiv"></div>
    <div id="divMain" class="MainDiv">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            <div id="divMasterContent" class="MainContentDiv">
            <div id="divMainSideBar1" class="MainSideBar1Div" style="margin-left: 610px;"></div>
            <div id="divMainSideBar2" class="MainSideBar2Div" style="margin-left: 811px;"></div>
            </div>

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div id="divFooterMenu" class="FooterMenuDiv"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**StyleSheet Code**

```
body
{
    padding-left: 100px;
    background-image: url("../../App_LocalResources/wood.jpg");
    width: 1000px;
}

.BannerDiv
{
    border: thin solid Brown;
    padding-left: 50px;     padding-right: 50px;
    background-color: White;
    height: 150px; width: 895px;
}

.MainDiv
{
    padding-top: 10px;

    height: 600px; width: 1000px; 
}

.MainContentDiv
{
    background-color: White;
    border: thin solid Brown;
    height: 600px; width: 600px;
}

.MainSideBar1Div
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: White;
    border: thin solid Brown;
    height: 600px; width: 170px;
    top: -2px;
}

.MainSideBar2Div
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: White;
    border: thin solid Brown;
    height: 600px; width: 170px;
    top: -605px;
}

.FooterMenuDiv
{
    border: thin solid White;
    height: 30px; width: 997px;
    background-color: Gray;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

At present I am running it on my local machine.

Comment: What is the background? A color? An image? How is it declared? CSS? Please include the relevant pieces of code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Once the page loads, click View Source to view the exact path of the background image it renders.

Another option: To check whether the path mentioned in the css is correct and reachable, replace it by an inline background setting of the head tag in the master page. If it works, the path is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the App_Localresources are added to the output directory when you publish the site? Right-click the wood.jpg in solution explorer and check that "Build option" is set to "Content".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66(VS.80).aspx

Btw...If your masterpage and content pages resides in different folders, I would recommend using site-root relative path instead of relative paths:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx

Comment: That is a great article, but Request.ApplicationPath can't be written in a CSS file.

Comment: That's true, but I meant the path to the MasterStyleSheet.css in the Masterpage.

Answer (score 1):

the **App_LocalResources is a protected folder** and asp.net not let the image readed from.

**Place your background image, and other images in an other folder**, eg on /images/

**To verify that** just try to see the folder...->
www.yoursite.com/App_LocalResources/

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have placed MasterPage & Default.aspx at different folder location. Try to place them at same level and see the difference.

As stylesheets path are considered according to webpage at runtime and according to Masterpage at design time.

The Ohter solution you can use is
Replace this line with

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Stylesheets/MasterStyleSheet.css" />
```

this new one

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets/MasterStyleSheet.css" />
```

I hope this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to make sure that, server can read your your BG path properly, as you can view it on your local PC, but when running on server the path may not be relative, or even the image isn't uploaded to the directory